# How can i run bash on a remote linux server

Tags: linux, bash

Lets say i have two servers on the same network:

```
db-test-1
db-test-2
```

On db-test-1, how can i run a bash command that executes on db-test-2? For example, on db-test-1, run a command that checks if a program is running on the remote server, e.g,

```
ps -ef |grep consul
```

I have to use the server name, not IP by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ssh keys:

1. On db-test1: generate a pair of ssh keys (ssh-keygen)
2. Append or copy .ssh/id_rsa.pub of db-test1 to .ssh/authorized_keys
3. on db-test1: ssh db-test2 *ps -ef | grep consul*

The first connection you will be ask if you trust the remote host. You can remote this by adding: *StrictHostKeyChecking no* in *.ssh/config*